# Android Calling Custom Adapter Methods within MainActivity

Tags: java, android

The below code lives in my main activity. I want to know if their is a way I can call methods using the instance of GridAdapter that was passed into the gridview.setAdapter() function.

GridAdapter is responsible for filling the gridview with images. On click I want to get the position it was clicked at AND the some data from the GridAdapter.

```
    // create a new GridView object
    GridView gridview = this.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id)
        {
            thisGridAdapter.someMethod(position);  //what I want to do
            Log.d("gridView", String.valueOf(position));
            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to a variable?

```
final GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this);
GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        adapter.someMethod(position);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, use the `GridView#getAdapter()` method and cast it to your adapter class:

```
final GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this));
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        ((GridAdapter) gridView.getAdapter).someMethod(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't even think of this. Thank you!